# Jetson TK1 Multiple Streams parallel execution

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Considering that Tk1 has single SM, is it really possible to run streams concurrently ? I have been unable to do so, even with latest vesions of cuda libraries.

So is it really possible ? any sample code would be great. The sample code under cuda Blas also runs sequential as show on visual profiler.

Also a better insight into what "Streams" are good for in a Single SM ?

[Already asked on nvidia dev forum, the forum isnt very active i think]

Comment: concurrent kernel execution is one aspect of stream parallelism.  concurrent kernel execution was broken on TK1 for a period of time. The problem should be rectified in the latest firmware for TK1, so make sure you have updated to the latest JetPack that supports TK1. Having said that, concurrent kernel execution is hard to witness, so it takes a specially crafted case to make it easily visible in the profiler. Apart from all that, streams allow for overlap of copy and compute.  However, copy operations should be avoided on Jetson since the memory is unified; they should be mostly unnecessary.

Comment: As stated in the original question, CUDA Blas samples do not show parallelism in visual Profiler either. And I am already on the latest jetPack. I'd like to know if it really is possible to have concurrent kernel exec on TK1. Secondly, it has only 1 SM processor, How does this relate to Cuda Streams created in code.

Answer (score 1):

With a single Kepler SM, it is not possible to run several streams concurrently. Kepler does not support preemption. This is not related to a CUDA version, rather related to the capability of the SM. Something related to preemption has be discussed for Pascal at GTC 2016, but nothing before.

Regarding the actual use of streams with single SM, some async functions may behave slightly differently between stream 0 and other streams. Hence, I assume some corner case of async memcopy and execution might benefit from streams with single SM - as TK1 device query reads that it has concurrent copy and exec with 1 copy engine. (even though it might be that ZeroCopy is a better approach on TK1).